# How to return cell result next to the already found cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pick up vba /vb.net in order to automate our report generation. I have no formal education or expertise, so please be gentle :D

Scenario is : I am building DB to keep track of truck equipment and which driver  drove the truck last. Whit a click of a button (btnLoadInfo) i would like to populate 3 textboxes , one with the last driver who drove the truck,one with the date when happened , and one with the last odometer . 
Criteria used for search will be truck or trailer.

Data is organized as follows 
Drivers are in column "E", 
Trucks are in column "D"
Date is in column "C"
ODometer is in column "G"

Task: Find last occurrence of specific string in range D:D and return its corresponding values in cells E, C and G.

So far i am being able to find the last occurrence in the specified column, but i can`t get offset to work and to assign them to the textbox controls.

If you notice when you click btnLoadInfo Driver and Truck fields are being removed from the listbox, which means i am manipulating them, but in a wrong way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
[Hyperlink to excel file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qP6bcHL5XwuO1mK0W6w6MlZRyqdiQHa5/view?usp=sharing)
 Private Sub btnLoadInfo_Click()

```
'Code for finding last ocurance of specific string. ATM code is returing last ocurance celladdresss
Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Dim DriverSearch As String
Dim searchTerm As Range

    'error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DataSH = Sheet1
        DriverSearch = cboTrucks.Value
        Set searchTerm = DataSH.Range("D1:D999").Find(what:=DriverSearch, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        If searchTerm Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Driver was not found"
        Else

        Reg1.Value = searchTerm
        searchTerm.Offset(0, 1).Value = tbPrevTruckDriver

        End If

errHandler:
    'Protect all sheets if error occurs
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " & _
Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why the C# tag?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I mean you've already got the result next to it by using `searchTerm.Offset(0,1)`

Comment: @Magnetron sorry, i just happen to notice that alot of C# pros answer vb /vba related questions

Comment: @Tom. I am getting error if i use the above method with the offset. I can`t assign it to the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If searchTerm is not nothing (check for this), then it should have Row and Column properties.

If you want the cell to the left of the found cell, then you would use:

```
DataSH.Cells(searchTerm.Row, searchTerm.Column - 1)
```

If you want the cell above the found cell, then you would use:

```
DataSH.Cells(searchTerm.Row - 1, searchTerm.Column)
```

Note that Column is a number, 1 being the A row, 2 being the B, etc.

Comment: Why not just use `searchTerm.Offset` there is no need to refer back to the sheet

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thank you, your method worked great and now i am populating the textboxes but nevertheless i am still getting an error

Comment: After the End If but before errHandler place a line that says "Exit Sub", so the errHandler section isn't called. Since the error number is 0, you have no error. Can you please accept my "answer" after the change? It should be an on screen option. Thanks.  Another option in the errHandler is to put the MsgBox in an if statement, only calling it if Err.Number > 0 –

Answer (score 0):

The above code from Ctznkane525 did the job for me and now i am populating the textboxes.
 [Populated textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdmdZ.png)

I am however getting an error ( before populating them, and upon clicking ok, they get populated)

[Error with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGxrD.png)

Current code

Private Sub btnLoadInfo_Click()

```
'Code for finding last ocurance of specific string. ATM code is returing last ocurance celladdresss
Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Dim DriverSearch As String
Dim searchTerm As Range

    'error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


        Set DataSH = Sheet1

        DriverSearch = cboTrucks.Value
        Set searchTerm = DataSH.Range("D1:D999").Find(what:=DriverSearch, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        If searchTerm Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Driver was not found"
        Else

        tbPrevTruckDriver = DataSH.Cells(searchTerm.Row, searchTerm.Column + 1)
        tbPrevTruckDate = DataSH.Cells(searchTerm.Row, searchTerm.Column - 1)
        tbPrevOdo = DataSH.Cells(searchTerm.Row, searchTerm.Column + 3)

        End If
errHandler:
    'Protect all sheets if error occurs
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " & _
Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"
```

End Sub

Comment: After the End If but before errHandler place a line that says  "Exit Sub", so the errHandler section isn't called.  Since the error number is 0, you have no error.  Can you please accept my "answer" after the change.  It should be an on screen option.  Thanks

Comment: Another option in the errHandler is to put the MsgBox in an if statement, only calling it if Err.Number > 0